# Why string 'all' == 0 return true

Tags: php, laravel

Why string `'all' == 0` return `true`, but `'all' == 1` return `false`. Honestly, the main question is why `'all' == 0` return `true`.

[image]

Comment: For more details see [this](https://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php) (especially the table at *Loose comparisons with ==*).

Comment: [They seem to have changed this behavior](https://3v4l.org/67A8D).

Comment: conditionally 'all' return false in bool. so basically false == false returns you true